# Enqueue sripts and styles only if function is called

Tags: php, plugin-development, functions, wp-enqueue-script

I'm using a function to display a gallery and I need to load its JS/CSS only if the gallery function is called. Both functions are in the custom plugin.

I have now the first function to enqueue scripts and styles and function itself:

```
function gallery_assets() {
            $upload_dir = wp_get_upload_dir();
            wp_enqueue_style('flex-gallery', trailingslashit( $upload_dir["baseurl"]).'gallery-assets/css/flex-gallery.css');

            wp_enqueue_script('flex-gallery-jquery', trailingslashit( $upload_dir["baseurl"]).'gallery-assets/js/jquery.min.js');
            wp_enqueue_script('flex-gallery', trailingslashit( $upload_dir["baseurl"]).'gallery-assets/js/flex-gallery.js');
            } 
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'gallery_assets', 10);
function portfolio_gallery () {}
```

My question is: How I can execute gallery_assets() from portfolio_gallery()?

Thank you!

Comment: How is `portfolio_gallery` called?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of two functions, just put the gallery assets code inside of the portfolio gallery function.

Or nest it. Nesting is kinda ugly though.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is: How I can execute gallery_assets() from
>   portfolio_gallery()?

Unfortunately, you haven't given any indication as to how `portfolio_gallery()` is executed.  Is it called from another function/location? Or is it hooked to something?

It's actually more than likely that you don't need to execute `gallery_assets()` from `portfolio_gallery()`.  If `portfolio_gallery()` runs in the body (such as displaying content), `gallery_assets()` it would already have executed.  You've hooked it to the `wp_enqueue_scripts` action, and as written, it will execute in the head.

[This page in the Codex has a general list of actions and the order they come in.](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference)